# Generate Auto Increment Unique ID with Month & Year Prefix

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql query:

```
select  id, concat('RJM-', id) as transid from rjm
```

Which generate this result: `RJM-00001`

How can i make this in to this format: `RJM-MMYY-00001`

MM-month
YY-year

and i want to reset the incremental of '`000001`' when MMYY is changed.
For example i have `RJM-0219-052342`, the month is february and year is 2019. When the current month is March, 2019 then the unique id will reset to `RJM-0319-000001`.

Thanks!

Comment: I just don't see the point of storing derived data (if that's the implication)

Answer (score 0):

Below would be one way.

```
select  concat('RJM-', 
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_date()), '%m%y'), '-', 
case 
when day(current_date())=1 then '0001' --condition will reset id to 0001 for the first day of month 
else '0005' end
);
```

Output -
RJM-0219-0005